# How to perform code navigation in Django using docker

Tags: django

I could not find the code definition using `Ctrl + click` when I use `Docker` + `Django` in my project, since source code are now in container. How could I configure my VScode to enable code navigation?

I am using `django-cookiecutter` with `use-docker` configuration.

Comment: Some configuration, works totally fine on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not a statically typed language and the IDE or editor sometimes can't find the exact code definition.

See: vscode [code navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved), also: [Difference](https://hackernoon.com/statically-typed-vs-dynamically-typed-languages-e4778e1ca55) between statically typed language and dynamically typed language